# How to know which drawable resource is selected

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-resources

I am using Android Studio 1.2.1.1.  When editing an xml layout file such as "\large-hdpi\my-layout.xml", a preview is generated in the right hand panel. In this case I have the Nexus 7 selected which is 800x1280. I *expect* the layout to be "large-hdpi" which it is, and I *expect* "hdpi" drawables to be used which it are not.  The problem is, I see no way to find out exactly which drawable resource folder is being used for the preview. Sorry if it's obvious but I just don't see it.

Comment: if you need just the dimension you can click the image in the preview while looking at the xml, but i am not sure its important to know while looking at the preview which image is being used. try looking design view and preview all screen sizes to see how the image actually looks

Comment: Did you try with density, check density using getResource().getDisplayMetrics().getDensity and then check it against Density constants, ie. DensityMetrics.DENSITY_MDPI etc?

Comment: @inner_class7, When I click on the image in the preview while looking at the xml, I don't see the dimension displayed anywhere.  This is exactly what I need.  Even better would be to tell me which bucket it's grabbing from.  This is purely for troubleshooting.  Technically I guess it's tvdpi but that doesn't seem to correspond with any of the Google documentation.

Comment: dimension of the view is in the top right but this doesn't tell you about density its a px by px dimension

Comment: @inner_class7, Hmmmmm... Mine doesn't display the dimension in the top right.